# EF core rename and duplicate table during migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have faced with some strange behaviour of EF core(7.0.2).
I have 2 entities

```
[Table("target"), Index(nameof(Prefix), IsUnique = true)]
internal sealed class TargetEntity
{
    [Key, Column("target_id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Column("name"), MaxLength(64)]
    public string Name { get; set; } = default!;

    [Column("description"), MaxLength(256)]
    public string? Description { get; set; }

    [Column("prefix")]
    public char Prefix { get; set; }

    [Column("group_link_id")]
    public long? GroupLinkId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(GroupLinkId))]
    public GroupEntity GroupLink { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

and

```
[Table("group")]
internal sealed class GroupEntity
{
    [Key, Column("group_id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Column("name"), MaxLength(64)]
    public string Name { get; set; } = default!;

    [Column("description"), MaxLength(256)]
    public string? Description { get; set; }

    [Column("group_link_id")]
    public long? GroupLinkId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(GroupLinkId))]
    public GroupEntity GroupLink { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

And here the definition ib dbcontext

```
internal DbSet<GroupEntity> GroupEntity { get; set; } = default!;
internal DbSet<TargetEntity> TargetEntity { get; set; } = default!;
```

I don't have `OnModelCreating` method

Few weeks ago I made initial migration, and then another two migrations, and it works properly.

Yesterday, after some code-revision I tried to make another one migration and I noticed that there were something strange generated in migration.
EF core generated for no reason rename instruction for these two tables

```
        migrationBuilder.RenameTable(
            name: "target",
            newName: "Target");

        migrationBuilder.RenameTable(
            name: "group",
            newName: "Group");
```

And some of column renaming instructions.
And EF core generated the createtable methods for these tables

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "group",
            columns: table => new
            {
                groupid = table.Column<long>(name: "group_id", type: "bigint", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("Npgsql:ValueGenerationStrategy", NpgsqlValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityByDefaultColumn),
                name = table.Column<string>(type: "character varying(64)", maxLength: 64, nullable: false),
                description = table.Column<string>(type: "character varying(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                grouplinkid = table.Column<long>(name: "group_link_id", type: "bigint", nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_group", x => x.groupid);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_group_group_group_link_id",
                    column: x => x.grouplinkid,
                    principalTable: "group",
                    principalColumn: "group_id");
            });
```

etc.

So, I've tried to solve the problem and did a lot of actions, even deleted all migrations and droped db, but I failed in my tries.
Because even if I make new initial migration - ef core make two createtable methods for each of these two tables.
[proof image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4Wlz.png)

Does anyone know what I gonna do with such a mysterious problem?
Because searching in google didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Can you please post a full [mre] somewhere?

Comment: Dear @Guru-Stron, thank you. I've found mistake when I tried to prepare MRE for you.
The mistake was in the next class, when I refer to model, not to entity.
Like
---
```public long? TargetId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey(nameof(TargetId))]
internal Target? Target { get; set; }```

---

instead of


``` lang-cs
public long? TargetId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey(nameof(TargetId))]
internal TargetEntity? TargetEntity { get; set; }```